# verb conjugation

Tags: conjugation

I have a brief question on verb conjugation.

I'm aware of the standard ones like, for example, the verb trinken conjugates to 
ich trinke 
du trinkst 
er/sie/es trinkt

But when referring to a general person, such as a random boy, it is

> Der Junge trinken Wasser

Here trinket is conjugated to trinken as opposed to trinket etc.
Is there a specific rule for this type of conjugation?

Comment: How do you come to the impression, that it is 'Der Junge trinken Wasser'? It is 'trinkt'. And the last sentence has to be 'Here trinken is conjugated to ... ' but obviously based on wrong assumptions too, so hard to correct.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. *trinket* is not (at least not in modern German) a valid German verb form. And the correct form of your example would be *Der Junge trinkt Wasser*. Correcting these faults somehow invalidates your question. Also I'm lost what "general person" you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Singular:
Ich trinke, 
du trinkst,
er / sie / es trinkt

Plural:
wir trinken, 
ihr trinkt,
sie trinken

So the sentence is:

> Der Junge (er) trinkt Wasser.

Another option does not exist. 
"Der Junge trinken Wasser." is wrong.

"Trinken" is only correct, when you speak about several boys, for example

> Die Jungen trinken Wasser.

Answer (score 0):

I not a grammar expert, *just* a native speaker, but I'd say you've got something wrong.

a) "trinket" is not a verb I've ever come across in my life (although it does exist as "2. Person Plural Präsens im Kunjunktiv I" - [see here](http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-trinken.html))

b) "der Junge (noun! therefore a capital "J") trinkt Wasser" is a very normal case of 3rd person simple present, just as you have quoted

> the verb trinken conjugates to: ich trinke, du trinkst, **er/sie/es trinkt**

Hence, I don't think there is a special kind of conjugation here...

Answer (score 0):

I think your question comes down to what is meant by 'the third person'.

1st person - the person or people speaking or writing (I, me, we or us)

2nd person - the person or people being written or spoken to (you)

3rd person - everyone/everything else (random strangers, the dog, the weather, organisations, situations, moods, periods of time etc.)

So the random boy would be in the 3rd person (er trinkt).